# Suggestions for Dressing up blog for the holidays

Tags: plugins

I was wondering what you guys are doing to dress up your blogs ?

any plugins that add some cool effects like snow flakes, maybe greeting popup, footer, music, header rotation, list of new years resolution, wishlist widget display ....

I was wondering what you doing to dress up your blog around holidays, maybe we can compile a nice list together - but god forbid - do them all together in one blog :P

thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Themes

The [Free Themes Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) at WordPress.org just updated its list of featured themes, and now includes two different Christmas-related themes:

- [Red Christmas](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/red-christmas)
- [This Christmas](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/this-christmas)

## Plug-ins

The most commonly used holiday/Winter plug-in is the snow plug-in featured on WordPress.com:

- [Snow Storm](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/snowstorm/)

There are also 35 different plug-ins in the repository that match a search for "[Christmas](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=christmas&sort=)."  I tried looking for anything freely available for other holidays, but I have yet to find anything ... so if you want to write a plug-in to celebrate Hanukkah, I think it would be very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is don't [over]do it. :)

US-based folks tend to forget their holidays aren't worldwide. It gets annoying fast to get blasted with tons of holiday-ish stuff for holiday you don't care about from every other site (not even mention tons of offers to promote stuff that start to pour into email).

So I don't dress blog because I won't do to my readers something I find annoying when done to myself.

Of course there is nothing wrong with **some** holiday elements... But there is a lot of wrong with giant snowflakes flying across screen and spiking your CPU load.